# added element under mutation observer throws an error after removed

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Hi,

I have html code like this

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

then I have this observer so a function is executed if an element with data-added is added.

```
 new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
     for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes[0].dataset.added) {
       loadstuff();
      }
     }
    }).observe(box, {childList: true});
```

it works but as I remove the element I get this error on console:

Uncaught TypeError: mutation.addedNodes[0] is undefined

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dc63r7bg/1/

How can I get rid of that error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function addit() {
  box.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<span id="elm" data-added="yes">element</span>');
}

function removeit() {
  document.getElementById("elm").remove();
}

new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes[0]?.dataset.added) {
      console.log('added');
    }
  }
}).observe(box, {
  childList: true
});
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="addit()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeit()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: You will want to also add one after `.dataset`, `addedNodes` contains Nodes, not only Elements.